# OAuth: Send Access Token and Get User data

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, access-token, google-oauth

I am trying Google OAuth.I am developing web application running on IBM webSphere server. Application's framework is SpringMVC.

I am trying to get userinfo.profile. I have **successfully get Access Token** and could not find a way to use this token and get user information.

I was redirecting browser to this URL `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token="+access.getAccessToken();` but getting error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "authError",
    "message": "Invalid Credentials",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Invalid Credentials"
 }
}
```

Am I using this access token fine or should I send request in some other form?

I am sending request in this way:

```
GenericUrl shortenEndpoint = new GenericUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo");
HttpRequest request1 = rf.buildGetRequest(shortenEndpoint);
GoogleHeaders headers = new GoogleHeaders();
headers.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
headers.setAuthorization("OAuth " + accessToken); 
request1.setHeaders(headers);
HttpResponse shortUrl = request1.execute();
```

After giving my Access Token in this URL in browser

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=******
```

I got

```
{
 "issued_to": "*****************",
 "audience": "*****************",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener",
 "expires_in": 3515,
 "access_type": "online"
}
```

Comment: Does it also fail if you send the token using the `Authorization` header ?

Comment: I did not try that. Can you show me any example sending this header?

Comment: Could you detail how you sent the http request ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the tokeninfo response, there is a mismatch between the scope for which the token was issued and the API you are trying to access. You seem to have an access token for https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener scope. If you want to user the userinfo API, you should obtain a token for the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email scopes.

Comment: You beauty. What a dig. If there were option to up-vote more than once then I will do this ten times.

Comment: How can I use both scopes?

Comment: Great finding @vlatko, thanks. Imran, for multiple scopes, you have to pass them in your url. They have to be space delimited. Example: `scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`

Comment: @vlatko Hey vlatko, I couldn't find any contact info on your profile, so I'll try to contact you here and I'll delete the comment later. Your name seems Macedonian, so could you give me your email so I can reach out and get your advice about programming jobs?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your authorization header is incorrect.

Try with : `headers.setAuthorization("OAuth " + accessToken);`

Comment: Ok can you check that you token is still valid ? You can call https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=`yourToken`  to check it.

Comment: It returns some data that means token is fine but having error when using in Application. Question edited for token.

Comment: Yeah token seems fine. Does the request using the `access_token=` parameter also fails in a browser or just from your app ? Also try to force the http method to `GET` in your code.

Comment: Then? Can you tell any other way to send token through application? Am I missing something?

Comment: I hit this URL https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=*********** but same error. In my app method is GET.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas here. By any chance does this endpoint: `googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=` works better ?